# Adobe Air iOs Packaging Error when it contains "Resources" folder. Why?

Tags: air, app-store, adobe, packaging, application-loader

I'm currently developing iOS app via Air 17. I double checked the certificates and provisioning profiles and they are OK. When I add application icons for iOS packager it will make a folder named "Resources" which is in .ipa output file. After tons of tests I figured out that Application Loader 3.0 does not allow this folder to be contained and gives this error:

> air the package does not contain an info.plist

If I manually rename or remove the "Resources" folder It will be fine and pass the first step but after checking the .ipa file with app store it says:

> ERROR ITMS-90035: Invalid signiture.

Please help if you faced this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I change the folder named "Resources" before packaging and the problem solved.

Comment: What do you mean by *"change the folder"*? Perhaps you meant to say "change to the folder"?